# List upcoming tasks in a Celery chain

Tags: python, celery

When I dispatch a chain of tasks, I would like to later on be able to later list all tasks that are still waiting to be picked up by a worker. For example:

```py
@app.task
def example():
    sleep(10)

c = chain(example.s(), example.s(), example.s(), example.s())
c.apply_async()
```

After starting the chain, I can get the completed tasks from the results backend, and the currently executing task by inspecting the workers, but I don't know how to list the tasks that are still waiting in the chain. As long as the chain variable, `c`, is in scope we can list all the tasks of the chain, but I would like to be able to do this outside of the variable's scope.

For my implementation specific details, I'm using `django-celery-results` with a `redis` broker.

I have tried inspecting the workers with

```py
i = celery.control.inspect()
print(i.scheduled())
print(i.active())
print(i.reserved())
```

and looking at the `AsyncResult` of the currently executing task

```py
a = AsyncResult(currently_executing_task_id)
print(dir(a))
```

but couldn't find anything related to the upcoming tasks. Looking at data in my broker (Redis) also showed nothing relevant.

Comment: Task result has a property called `children` that can help you navigate the whole graph.

Comment: @DejanLekic, when I tested it if the task has a status of `PENDING`, the `children` attribute is `None`, and if the status is `STARTED`, it's always an empty list. Even if the empty list is some configuration error on my setup, I would still need to be able to get all the children of `PENDING` tasks too; the Celery docs are unfortunately very lacking in explaining what the children should contain and when.

Comment: Do you have workers subscribed to the queue to which you have sent the task(s)?

Answer (score 1):

try creating a loop after: `a = AsyncResult(currently_executing_task_id)`.
The loop should look something like this:

```
for i, task in enumerate(a.parent.children):
    if not task.ready():
        ...........
```

instead of an ellipsis, you do the most common output of tasks that the worker has not yet taken.